# Using FragmentActivity in Android Project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to figure out how to use Fragments in my Android App to allow for tabbed/swipe navigation between activities. Right now I have a MainActivity and another TestActivity, MainActivity extends Activity but the other TestActivity extends ListActivity.

To use Fragments I need to extend both of these using FragmentActivity or Fragment, which is fine for MainActivity but I'm not sure how to change the TestActivity to keep my current functionality of ListActivity but also extend FragmentActivity. Not sure if that makes sense, but I'm not too sure where to go...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend both. You'll have to include a ListView in your Activity (which extends FragmentActivity)

See this: [android combination of fragmentactivity and listactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983578/android-combination-of-fragmentactivity-and-listactivity)

**Edit:**
You might check out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_overview if you need a resource to help create listviews.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to include a ListView in the Activity...sorry I am new to Android. One other thing I looked into is ListFragment rather than ListActivity, however, I am getting an error with the setContentView() method of ListActivity...